# User_tables Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have created several tables in Oracle but I can't find them using for example the query

```
select * from user_tables where table_name='temp';
```

But I'm sure the table temp does exist, I checked it.

Comment: Unlike the `CREATE TABLE` command, the `SELECT` command as used in the OP, does not allow the table to be specified without quotes. That is because the `SELECT` statement is just listing pure data. It really doesn't know it's a table name. It could be a person's name, an object name, anything. So, you must use the single quotes ... but, when you use single quotes, the case MUST match. And, database tables are by default upper case, in Oracle. You probably didn't use quotes in the `CREATE TABLE` command, which means your table is in upper case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table name has to be in upper case in user_tables.

```
select * from user_tables where table_name='TEMP';
```

An example:

```
SQL> create table bogus (name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> select table_name from user_Tables where table_name = 'bogus';

no rows selected

SQL> select table_name from user_Tables where table_name = 'BOGUS';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
BOGUS
```

*** This is an edit to explain a little of what what said in the comments section of this answer.  In short, you can create lower/mixed case objects in Oracle, but the issue becomes having to wrap the object names in double quotes each time you reference them.

An Example

```
SQL> create table "bogus" (name varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> select table_name from user_tables where table_name = 'BOGUS';

no rows selected

SQL> select table_name from user_tables where table_name = 'bogus';

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
bogus

SQL> select * from bogus;
select * from bogus
          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> select * from "bogus";

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: The CREATE TABLE is actually doing this : `create table "BOGUS" ("NAME" varchar2(10));` - We (all) constantly use an implicitly converted literal of the command as shown in the reply above. Problem is, it can be confusing for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from user_tables where upper(table_name)=upper('temp');
```